# Joining two tables with multiple field sorting in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables and I have to join it. table structures are

> tblproducts --> id(int,pk), name(varchar)
>
> tblphotos ---> id(int,pk), productid(int,fk), photo(varchar), display_order(int)

There can be more than one photos for each product, I need to get one photo with lowest display_order.

I need, tblproducts.id, tblproducts.name, tblphotos.photo(photo with least display_order) also I need to get the whole list as tblproducts.id in ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select tblproducts.id, tblproducts.name, (Select Top 1 tblphotos.photo FROM tblphotos, tblproducts Where tblphotos.productid = tblproducts.id Order By display_order)
From tblproducts, tblphotos
Where tblproducts.id = tblphotos.productid
Order by  tblproducts.id
```

**EDIT**: Oppss! I didn't see [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) tag. This is for MSSQL by the way.

Yes this query looks like repeating. I should delete `Where` clause.

```
Select tblproducts.id, tblproducts.name, (Select Top 1 tblphotos.photo FROM tblphotos, tblproducts Where tblphotos.productid = tblproducts.id Order By display_order)
From tblproducts
Order by  tblproducts.id
```

Comment: thanks I changed it like

Select tblproducts.id, tblproducts.name, (Select  tblphotos.photoname FROM tblphotos, tblproducts Where tblphotos.productid = tblproducts.id order by tblphotos.displayorder asc limit 1 )
From tblproducts, tblphotos
Where tblproducts.id = tblphotos.productid
Order by  tblproducts.id 
but product name is repeating

Comment: this query not returning the exact result

Comment: I think we should delete Where clause in query. Because when we equalize tblproducts.id = tblphotos.productid is the reason of repeating.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the following query but it should work, give it a try:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.name, f.photo 
FROM
    tblproducts p,
    (
        SELECT productid, MIN(display_order) AS min_display_order 
        FROM tblphoto 
        GROUP BY productid
    ) AS t,
    tblphoto f 
WHERE 
    p.id = t.productid AND 
    t.productid = f.productid AND 
    t.min_display_order = f.display_order 
ORDER BY p.id
```

Comment: @JohnK I have updated my answer. Previously I wasn't giving an alias to `MIN(display_order)`. It should be fixed now.